# Отличие вызова метода через одну точку от вызова через две точки

Tags: flutter, dart

Чем отличается вызов метода через одну точку от вызова через две точки? В чем нюанс? Спасибо. 
***через одну точку ошибки нет***

```
 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  _controller.dispose();
 }
```

***через две точки ошибки нет***

```
@override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  _controller..dispose();
 }
```

***через одну точку ошибка есть***

```
@override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller = AnimationController(
   vsync: this,
   duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
  ).forward();
 }
```

***через две точки ошибки нет***

```
@override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller = AnimationController(
   vsync: this,
   duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
  )..forward();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

думаю основное что

так можно

```
void doSomething() {
  someObject..step1()
    ..step2()
    ..text = 'wtf';
 }
```

а с одной это будет так

```
void doSomething() {
  someObject.step1();
  someObject.step2();
  someObject.text = 'wtf';
 }
```

подробнее [тут](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation-)

> Cascades (..) allow you to make a sequence of operations on the same
> object. In addition to function calls, you can also access fields on
> that same object. This often saves you the step of creating a
> temporary variable and allows you to write more fluid code.
>
> если кратко более гибкий код

а вашем примере камней никаких нет.

Comment: Уважаемый Aziz Umarov! Огромное Вам спасибо!